# Error copying SQL Server database from one server to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

I have to copy a database from one server to another so from SSMS, in my case on SQL Server 2012, I am going to use the copy wizard under "Tasks -> Copy Database..." as explained [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b43b4/copy-database-from-one-server-to-another-server-in-sql/).

In "Configure Destination Database (1 of 1)" dialog window, the "Destination database files" table is empty, neither `.mdf` nor `.ldf` files are listed, table is empty.

[image]

Below two errors appear:

[image]
[image]

Also I have below doubt: Is source server disk space being used during the copy? I want to do the copy without using source server disk space since it is low.

Comment: I'd love to help, but I don't speak Spanish. can you translate the errors to English?

Comment: @Greg First error: 'File is a Directory' column does not belong to Table table (copy database wizard). And second error more or less: can not select a non-existing cell (0. 0. 0. 0). Parameter Name: SelectionBlocks (copy database wizard)

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way will be 
Backup the DB (with compression)
Copy the .bak file to Destination server 
Restore it.

Comment: I agree but I would like to understand why those errors occurs when using copy wizard and solve them if possible. In fact in later versions of Sql Server copy wizard is no longer available as far as I know.